# android use getfilter method for SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using simpleAdapter for listview , and I want to filter the list using the method `getfilter()` but when I try it give me `The method getFilter() is undefined for the type ListAdapter`
any help please.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html. you have getFilter. post the code pls and check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

dont use SimpleAdapter with filtering feature as SimpleFilter used by SimpleAdapter has sime bugs (at least in v2.2 it assumes that all values in a Map have to be Strings)